# AngularJS Custom Filter in ng-repeat doesn't get pushed Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem with my custom filter function in angular.

This is the filter function:

```
.filter('itemFilter', function($rootScope) {

        return function(input) {
            var filtered = [];
            angular.forEach(input, function(item) {
                if(item.user_id === $rootScope.userData._id && item.active === true){
                    filtered.push(item);
                }
            });
            //console.log(filtered);
            return filtered;
        }

    });
```

The filter does what it should do, but when i want to push a new Object in the item Array, the filter does not get the new Object. The new Item is pushed in the array correctly, though.

This is where the item is pushed in the DB and in the rootScope. The function is located inside a factory and called in the controller.

Function in the factory:

```
var addItem = function(item){
            $http.post("http://localhost:3333/items", item)
                .success(function (response) {
                    $rootScope.items.push(item);
                    $log.debug(response);
                })
                .error(function (err){
                    $log.error("item was not added: "+err);
                });
        };
```

Call of the function in the controller:

```
    $scope.itemObj = {"user_id": $rootScope.userData._id, "group_id": $rootScope.userData.group_id};

    $scope.addItem = function() {
        console.log($scope.itemObj);
        dataFactory.addItem($scope.itemObj);
        $modalInstance.close();
        $scope.itemObj = {"user_id": $rootScope.userData._id, "group_id": $rootScope.userData.group_id};
    };
```

The whole array with all items is located in the rootScope.

This is the part where I call the ng-repeat:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in items | itemFilter | filter: qry | orderBy: '-created'">
    <tr popover="{{item.description}}" popover-trigger="mouseenter">
        <td>{{item.amount}}</td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.price | currency:"EUR€ "}}</td>
        <td>{{item.list}}</td>
        <td ng-controller="EditItemCtrl"><a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open(item)">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteItem(item)">Delete</a></td>
        <td ng-controller="BoughtItemCtrl">
            <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="open(item)">Bought</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p ng-show="!item.active">NO</p>
            <p ng-show="item.active">YES</p>
        </td>
    </tr></tbody>
```

Is there any way to tell the filter, that a new item has been added to the array? After reloading the page, everything works fine, because the filter gets the whole items array.

Comment: Please show the controller .How you defined the 'items' ?

Comment: It would help if you provide a working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/).

Comment: Remove `$scope.$apply(function()`, just push instead,.

Comment: the 'items' array is initialized in the .run function via $http.get. So after a reload the array is filled with objects from the DB

Comment: @dfsq i tried that before. Also does not work :/

Comment: Sharing a plunker would allow us to look more closely to the issue and the cause. Also, you must check if the subsequent filter aren't blocking the item from rendering.

Comment: you can use $scope in your controller for your array, use factory just to return the web call, with the use of promises you can get in .success the object and push in the array this way the filter will do it's job. Let me know if u need help, pass this discussion to chat.

Answer (score 0):

I think i fixed the problem.

Instead of pushing the 'item' into the array I am now pushing the 'response' into it.

```
var addItem = function(item){
        $http.post("http://localhost:3333/items", item)
            .success(function (response) {
                $rootScope.items.push(response);
                $log.debug(response);
            })
            .error(function (err){
                $log.error("item was not added: "+err);
            });
    };
```

The pushed response has an now '_id'-value (which is generated by the MonogDB). I am not sure if the missing id was the problem.

Maybe you have an answer for that.
Thanks anyway for the quick responses.